# Download A Binary Data as CSV in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, blob

I have a response from api which is supposed to download a data in excel sheet.

But instead, I am getting the binary data inside excel sheet.

This is the format of the binary I am getting:

```
PK���ï¿½Rï¿½Vï¿½ï¿½!ï¿½��ï¿½�����xl/workbook.xmlï¿½Pï¿½nï¿½0ï¿½kï¿½ï¿½!mï¿½pï¿½R!ï¿½gcï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½@>ï¿½v�ï¿½zï¿½É³ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½r=:ï¿½.ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|VC/ï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½9ï¿½OXï¿½ï¿½cs
ï¿½tï¿½ï¿½ï¿½&ï¿½Ð§44ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½67Aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½zï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½f ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Qï¿½!ï¿½Pï¿½#&gobNï¿½ï¿½vï¿½eï¿½ï¿½%ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½~ï¿½`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½Jï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½DJï¿½"ï¿½Bï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½`'Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½Dï¿½O'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Å’ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½SQ    ~ï¿½6ï¿½mU5ï¿½Ø˜ï¿½Ve|
...
```

This is my download function in react js:

```
export const downloadSettlement = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post(`${ApiEndpoints.DOWNLOAD}`, payload, {
      headers: GET_HEADER_PS,
    });
    const response = await res.data;
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/xlsx' });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.location.href = url;
    } else {
      return { status: "error", detail: "Error in download" };
 
};
```

How can I make this download work. It is working perfectly on swagger where the endpoint is hosted.